# laplacian eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

Suppose $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ is the minimal eigenvalue of the (minus) Laplacian with zero Dirichlet condition in a domain $\Omega$. How do I prove that if I take a smaller domain $\bar\Omega$ contained in $\Omega$, then $\lambda_1(\bar\Omega)>\lambda_1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Do you know how to characterize $\lambda_1$ with a variational principle?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean...

Comment: If you mean Rayleigh formula - I am familiar with it, but still can't succeed proving the above

Comment: If the domain is made smaller, the Rayleigh quotient is computed over a smaller set of functions and therefore its minimum cannot become smaller. This proves the inequality with $\ge$.